# Hover Text for Zest GraphViewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, zest

I'd like to be able to modify the hover text on a node in the zest graph viewer. Does anybody know how to do this programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean tooltip over a node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GraphViewer has to have a `LabelProvider` which could implement `IEntityStyleProvider` which has a method `public IFigure getTooltip(Object entity)` to implement. I think there is nothing else to do.